# How to turn generic widgets into responsive widgets

Tags: responsive-design

We offer a widget which is incorporated into random websites by injecting a div into a predetermined location on pages (not as iframe).

A good example is 'people who bought this also bought' widgets in eCommerce websites. The div size is usually fixed.

We need to provide a cross browser/device responsive widget.

How should we redesign the widget to make it responsive?

Are there general design guidelines or best practices you can recommend?

Comment: Are you sure you want to make the widget itself responsive?

Comment: This is an implementation question - I reckon the guys at SO will be able to give more help.

Comment: @Izhaki no, this wouldn't be well received on stack overflow. They'd need to see significantly more details here - showing what code has been implemented and explanation as to why it's not working. They need you to have exhausted all research and still be stumped before they'll be able to help. there's none of that in this question in its current form.

Comment: @JonW, I think this is not off topic. It's a question of how to visually adapt the segment to different displays, not on how to implement this adaptation. However, it would be easier to answer this if the question contained an image or a wireframe of how it currently looks.

Comment: @DannyVarod that may be true but as it reads it seems like more of an implementation question - as many people seem to think also. However with some rewording it can be reopened.

Comment: @JonW how about now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your layout is already responsive. Change to widgets to a % width and %.

If you want to see an example, check out bootstrap (Twitter) or PureCss (Yahoo), that's where i learned the most.

Comment: Thanks, the reference to http://purecss.io/grids/ helped